# generate 7 digits

Tags: java, stringbuilder, memoization

Given a phone keypad as shown below:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
  0
```

So far I have this...
I have already caluclated all the possible moves from starting position and filled an array called `MoveArray` to help with memoization I am storing the call (i.e. `printoutArr`).

I am trying to recursively build the 7 letter string but I am not getting anywhere.This is where I'm stuck. Any help on this pleas?!?!

Comment: This is a hard problem.  Do you plan to use BFS or DFS?  And how do you plan to keep track of duplicate moves and cycles?

Comment: Checking && this.printoutArr[startingPos][i]==false I set the flag to be true so no numbers are generated again.

Answer (score 1):

I've used Java 8 in this answer. Let me know if you want me to covert to not use streams.

I would suggest splitting the problem into two parts. The first is the algorithm for defining the potential moves for each piece and the second is the recursion to get all combinations.

For the first problem, start with an interface:

```
public interface MoveGenerator {
    IntStream nextPositions(Integer position);
}
```

You could just use `Function<Integer,IntStream>` but defining your own interface makes things a bit more obvious.

You can then define implementations for this interface for each of pieces. That's pretty trivial once you've defined the array of legal moves. See the addendum below for a more elegant solution that doesn't require the arrays.

```
int[][] legalBishopMoves = {{7, 9}, {5, 9}, {4, 6}, {5, 7}...};
MoveGenerator bishopMoves = pos -> Arrays.stream(legalBishopMoves[pos]);
```

The second problem is actually relatively simple. It takes a starting position and a `MoveGenerator` and uses recursion to generate all the strings:

```
void getCombinations(String combination, int position, MoveGenerator generator) {
    if (combination.length() == 7) {
        System.out.println(combination);
    } else {
        generator.nextPositions(position)
            .forEach(pos -> getCombinations(combination + pos, pos, generator);
    }
}
```

You can call this like `getCombinations("", 4, bishopMoves)`

**Addendum**

I don't particularly like having static arrays representing rules in my code so I created an alternative that generates the moves from the basic rules for each piece:

```
int col(int pos) {
    return pos == 0 ? 1 : (pos - 1) % 3;
}

int row(int pos) {
    return pos == 0 ? 2 : (pos - 1) / 3;
}

int rows(int from, int to) {
    return Math.abs(row(from) - row(to));
}

int cols(int from, int to) {
    return Math.abs(col(from) - col(to));
}

interface MoveTest {
    boolean isLegal(int rows, int cols);
}

MoveGenerator fromTest(MoveTest test) {
    return from -> IntStream.range(0, 10)
        .filter(to -> from != to)
        .filter(to -> test.isLegal(rows(from, to), cols(from, to)));
}

MoveGenerator bishopMoves = fromTest((r, c) -> r == c);
MoveGenerator knightMoves = fromTest((r, c) -> r + c == 3);
MoveGenerator rookMoves = fromTest((r, c) -> r == 0 || c == 0);
MoveGenerator queenMoves = fromTest((r, c) -> r == 0 || c == 0 || r == c); 
MoveGenerator kingMoves = fromTest((r, c) -> r <= 1 && c <= 1);
```

This works nicely, though I suggest you don't try any of the queen moves as you end up with a lot of strings!

I didn't add a pawn move because it wouldn't generate anything.

Answer (score 0):

I like @sprinter's way since it is more concise and takes advantage of Java 8.
But here's a more verbose way of solving this problem with enums:

first define a general interface describing the pieces' movements

```
interface Movement {
    int x();
    int y();
}
```

then we'll use an enum to implement one of the pieces' movements

```
enum BishopMovement implements Movement {
    //the names for the enum constants
    //indicate the direction of the movement and how far it goes
    UpLeft1( -1, -1 ),
    UpLeft2( -2, -2 ),
    UpRight1( 1, -1 ),
    UpRight2( 2, -2 ),
    DownRight1( 1, 1 ),
    DownRight2( 2, 2 ),
    DownLeft1( -1, 1 ),
    DownLeft2( -2, 2 );

    final int x, y;

    BishopMovement( int xOffset, int yOffset ){
        x = xOffset;
        y = yOffset;
    }

    @Override
    public int x() {
        return x;
    }

    @Override
    public int y() {
        return y;
    }    
}
```

here's another example with the Knight

```
enum KnightMovement implements Movement {
    //again, the names say which movement they represent
    UpLeft( -1, -2 ),
    UpRight( 1, -2 ),
    RightUp( 2, -1 ),
    RightDown( 2, 1 ),
    DownRight( 1, 2 ),
    DownLeft( -1, 2 ),
    LeftDown( -2, 1 ),
    LeftUp( -2, -1 );

    final int x, y;

    KnightMovement( int xOffset, int yOffset ){
        x = xOffset;
        y = yOffset;
    }

    @Override
    public int x() {
        return x;
    }

    @Override
    public int y() {
        return y;
    }
}
```

defining each piece like this is kinda tedious but I actually do like having the movements organized in an enum. Personal preference I suppose.

I'm gonna define the the keys in the keypad in an enum too

```
enum Key {
    //note that the order is important here
    //because we'll be using ordinal() to easily
    //convert between an int and a Key
    Zero( 1, 3 ),
    One( 0, 0 ),
    Two( 1, 0 ),
    Three( 2, 0 ),
    Four( 0, 1 ),
    Five( 1, 1 ),
    Six( 2, 1 ),
    Seven( 0, 2 ),
    Eight( 1, 2 ),
    Nine( 2, 2 ),
    None( -1, -1 ); //default constant

    final int x, y;

    Key( int xOffset, int yOffset ){
        x = xOffset;
        y = yOffset;
    }

    //overriding toString because it'll be easier
    //to record the moves
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String s = "";
        if( !this.equals( None ) )
            s += this.ordinal();
        return s;
    }
}
```

and finally, to the solution

```
public class Solution {    
    static Key[][] keypad;
    static final int x1 = 2, y1 = 3; //Key One will be at x=2, y=3

    static {
        keypad = new Key[7][10]; //extra padding
        for( int x = 0; x < 7; x++ ){
            for( int y = 0; y < 10; y++ ) {
                keypad[x][y] = Key.None; //set all the elements to the default
            }
        }
        for( Key k : Key.values() ) {
            keypad[x1+k.x][y1+k.y] = k; //set all the keys
        }
    }

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        int key = 1;
        int totalMoves = 7;
        String initialMovement = "-";
        String allPossibleMoves = recursiveSolve( key, totalMoves, initialMovement, BishopMovement.values() );
        //all the possible moves will be separated by spaces with a trailing space at the end
        System.out.print( allPossibleMoves );
    }


    static String recursiveSolve( int key, int movesLeft, String moves, Movement[] possibleMoves ) {
        String results="";
        if( movesLeft > 0 ){
            Key k = Key.values()[key], nextKey;
            for( Movement m : possibleMoves ){
                nextKey = keypad[x1+k.x+m.x()][y1+k.y+m.y()];
                if( !nextKey.equals( Key.None ) ) {
                    results += recursiveSolve( nextKey.ordinal(), movesLeft - 1, moves + nextKey, possibleMoves );
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            results = moves+" ";
        }
        return results;
    }
}
```